# how to sort a list view on text changed android

Tags: android, listview, sorting

i have been trying to filter my list view all day with referring SO solutions but was not able to do it. Hence i am pasting the code below for your reference to know exactly what i was doing.. please some one help me solve it and if possible edit my code or point out my mistake.. the list does not get filtered. thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be in your `publishResults` method. The results obtained from `performFiltering` are never applied to the object list inside the array adapter. The easy way to do this is to create a new `ArrayAdapter` with the filtered items and update your list view.

The default behavior of the array list is to filter on a prefix. If this is ok, you could just call `setFilterText` on the list view with the text to filter on without having to implement your own filtering.

Also, as a side, you might want to move your `Filter newFilter = null;` to outside your method. Otherwise you are creating the filter every time. And should not need to set constraint to the contents of `etsearch` inside your `performFiltering` method since you are invoking the filter with the text from the text watcher which should have the same string value.

Comment: thanks for the reply..could you please help me with the code..or edit my code pls

Comment: I don't have privileges to edit your post yet. You also didn't post enough code to fix as is. You are filtering a list of `Contacts` but your list view shows a list of `DeviceContacts`. Is that a subclass? If you change `contactarray` to a list of `Contacts` then you could then replace `notifyDataSetChanged` with `contactarray = new ArrayList<Contact>((Collection<Contract>)results.values);bindList();`.